# Chi-Square test between three pairs

Tags: statistics

this is probably going to be a very dumb question, so my apologies in advance for that.

Anyway, I'm looking to determine if there is a significant difference in the number of stories that mention candy, that mention fruit, or that mention neither candy nor fruit, between (a) the Times and the Post, (b) the Times and the Herald, and, (c) the Post and the Herald.

I ran this Chi-Square test with all three newspapers (from socscistatistics.com):

[Chi-Square contingency table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3VhX.png)

However, is that a correct approach to make these three separate conclusions?

Or do I need to - instead - run three separate Chi-Square tests: 
(1) the Times and the Post
(2) the Times and the Herald
(3) the Post and the Herald

Answer (score 0):

The chi-squared test you showed in your link is an excellent first step.
If you had rejected the null hypothesis that proportions of mentions of 
candy/fruit/neither are the same across all three newspapers, then it would
be worthwhile to investigate between which pairs of newspapers the
differences might lie. But you did *not* find evidence of such differences
in the $3 \times 3$ table, so it seems best to stop there. I assume you
did this test at the 5% level of significance.

However, you *could* run ${3 \choose 2} = 3$ comparisons between pairs
of newspapers: T vs. P, T vs. H, P vs. H. However, to keep error
probabilities within bounds for the whole project, you should do each of
three tests at level $\alpha = .05/3 = .0167 = 1.67\%.$ This is called
a 'Bonferroni multiple comparison procedure' (which you can google) because it is based on
Bonferroni's (probability) Inequality.

*Notes:* (a) I ran these 3 tests. P-values as follows. TP (.767), TH (.195), PH (.671). Nothing there, not even close. (b) I'm wondering if articles that
mentioned both fruit and candy are double-counted. (If there's much double counting, then assumptions for all of these analyses are violated, and
conclusions possibly invalid.) Better then to go by the
'main' mention, or to have categories candy/fruit/both/neither.

Answer (score 0):

Bruce - this is absolutely invaluable, thank you so much for this excellent and thorough response which answered my issue perfectly (I've logged-in under a different ID as I forgot to write-down my original password and can't seem to generate a replacement).

Comment: This is not an answer. It should go in comments.